# Symfony2 form type entity: Option is not selected

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I use a Symfony2 (2.3) entity form type to load the options of a HTML select from a Doctrine entity:

Class RoomFacilityType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'Bezeichnung', 'required' => false))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Speichern'));

    // add referenced object facility type
    $builder->add('facilityType', new FacilityTypeType());
}
```

Class FacilityTypeType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('type', 'entity', array('label' => 'Ausstattung', 'class' => 'xyz\abcBundle\Entity\FacilityType', 'property' => 'type'));
}
```

In the controller I create a form with a RoomFacility entity:

```
$formRoomFacility = $this->createForm(new RoomFacilityType(), $roomFacility);
```

The RoomFacility entity has a ManToOne relation to entity FacilityType.

When the form is rendered by a twig template, no option of the HTML select is selected (but when I use a text form type instead, the correct value ist displayed):

```
{{ form_widget(formRoomFacility.facilityType.type) }}
```

I have found questions about how to set an option selected by setting it's value explicitly, but that doesn't solve my problem either:

```
$formRoomFacility->get('facilityType')->setData($roomFacility->getFacilityType());
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following will do what you want:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'Bezeichnung', 'required' => false))
            ->add('type', 'entity', array('label' => 'Ausstattung', 'class' => 'xyz\abcBundle\Entity\FacilityType', 'property' => 'type'))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Speichern'))
    ;
}
```