# Symfony2 form field type entity not setting selected option on form edit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've the following FormBuilder in a Form/*Type.php class:

```
<?php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('tpmTargetId', null, array('label' => 'Target', 'required' => true))

        ->add('tpmSourcePropertyId', 'entity', array( 'label' => 'Global property', 'class' => 'TI\ML\SyncBundle\Entity\MlProperties'))

    ;
}
```

The problem is with the field ***tpmSourcePropertyId***, when creating a new entry it displays the correct options in the dropdown field and when saving it inserts the correct ID but when trying to edit that entry the dropdown defaults to option #1 instead of the saved ID.

If I render the field a type text it shows the correct ID stored.

I've seem [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228583/symfony2-form-type-entity-option-is-not-selected) but I seem to be already using the proposed solution.

What could I do to debug this? Thank you!

--------- UPDATED

*\config\doctrine\MlTargets.orm.yml*

```
    tarEmpPropertyId:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: true
        comment: ''
        column: tar_emp_property_id
```

*Entity\MlTargets.php*

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 */
private $tarEmpPropertyId;


/**
 * Set tarEmpPropertyId
 *
 * @param integer $tarEmpPropertyId
 * @return MlTargets
 */
public function setTarEmpPropertyId($tarEmpPropertyId)
{
    $this->tarEmpPropertyId = $tarEmpPropertyId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tarEmpPropertyId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getTarEmpPropertyId()
{
    return $this->tarEmpPropertyId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a property, you mean to reference an object.

On the database, the column will save the **id** of the object, but symfony will load the reference of it and you will manipulate an **object**.

So you can try to

```
->add('tpmSourceProperty', 'entity', array('label' => 'Global property', 'class' =>'TI\ML\SyncBundle\Entity\MlProperties'))
```

Comment: Thank you, if I remove the Id part then I get errors about property not found. I've updated the question and added more info on the YML and Entity files. Thank you!.

Comment: i think you just need set the *default option* of your dropdown to be the *loaded id*.

Comment: Thank you, but how could I access the loaded id in that context? That would be nice!

Comment: maybe this link could be helpful.. this guy needs set a default value for his dropdown too.. http://goo.gl/mJwgXy